# Selenium automation project is working on localhost but not working production

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

Here is my code. I have use nuget package `selenium`, chrome drive and chrome drive exe.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace selenium
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `not working` ?

Comment: project no getting any error and i also use try catch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable logs and check them. Possible problem may be that browser cannot be started (e.g. Chrome and ChromeDriver are not installed/configured). Another possibility could be that outgoing internet traffic is blocked, what typically happens on servers in production.